# My android phone is not displaying apps in the sd card

Tags: sd-card, app2sd

I open my settings and go to application manager. Then i move some apps to sd card. After that, i insert the sd card into another phone. But the apps doesn't appear. Help me pls.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work this way. The native [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) of Android does never move the entire app to the card – parts of it always remain in [internal-storage](/questions/tagged/internal-storage), as do the apps data.

There are advanced versions of the "App2SD principle" like [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd), where you can move the entire app including its data to the card (those will require [root](/questions/tagged/root)). But still, it wouldn't work to simply move the card to a different phone and have the apps there. On installation, apps have to be "registered with the system" to be used on the device, to e.g. deal with app permissions and more.

So in short: There is no way to simply "move an app to SD card" in order to use it on a different device. If you need to transfer an app, you will have to chose a different approach (e.g. create an [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) and restore that on the other device, or use an app doing that for you "on-the-fly", like [Helium - App Sync and Backup](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)).

For more details, please take a look at our [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info).

Answer (score 0):

That's because not all app data has been moved to sd card. If you look at App info(Settings->Apps->App that you moved to sd card) with your sd card in your first phone you will see that not all storage of an app has been transfered to sd card app. For example I have Firefox on my sd card but Storage shows how much MB does it take on phone or sd card:
Total: 48.11 MB, App: 6.53 MB (on phone), SD card app 37.59 MB, Data: 3.74MB, Sdcard data 256 kB.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply move apps from phone memory to sd from one phone to another.
You have only moved the storage data of app, not the actual app data.
If you want to move the apps from one phone to another. Try this[app2sd](https://m.apkpure.com/app2sd/braveheart.apps.app2sd). This is a cool app which moves the backup of apps to sd card from phone memory. And these apps can be installed in any other phones.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solution
1. Restart your phone
2. Go to settings > apps and clear the data of app that causes problem.
3. Head to settings > storage > unmount SD card, then click on mount SD card.
4. Just go to task manager and on the RAM tab, click to select and buttons and press clear button, your sd card shortcuts are now displayed.

[Source](http://ask.baatkar.com/question/why-is-my-android-phone-not-displaying-apps-installed-on-sd-card/)